# Is not recognized as an internal or external command eror using pyuic

Tags: python, command-line, pyuic

I created a .ui file. I have been trying to convert it to .py file using pyuic (i don't have Anaconda)

I am sure that I have pyuic.bat

and [it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGQIG.jpg)'s directory is

```
D:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
```

Then I open the directory of my .ui file. and i write cmd to address line. Afterward, I enter this command

```
D:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic.bat -x mygui.ui -o mygui.py
```

and i see this error message:

```
D:\Python35\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\pyuic.bat -x mygui.ui -o mygui.py is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'
```

edit: i solved using:

```
pyuic5 -x arayuz2.ui -o arayuz2.py
```

Comment: That error comes up quite often on here, did none of the existing posts help?

Comment: pretty sure its normally a python script file and not a batch file. like pyuic.py or something like that. also to run python scripts you gotta give command prompt a python path first (unless you already have that environment variable setup)

Comment: What do you mean by python path?